# increment operator on multiple values

Tags: php, post-increment

is there any way to post or per increment multiple variables with one increment operator.
i have 4 values on which i need to increment one value

```
$a = 1; $b = 3; $c = 45; $d = 10;
```

normally we use this method but instead of incrementing them individually like

```
++$a; ++$b; ++$c; ++$d;
```

can i do something like encapsulate them in brackets and then globally perform increment on them

```
++($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

i have tried the above statement but it don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) along with an array of referenced variables

```
array_map(function(&$var){  $var++; }, array(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d));
```

Comment: That's more verbose the original increments. :)

Comment: Replace `function($var)` with `function(&$var)` ;)

Comment: But why have you removed references to variables in array? It will work only with references in both places...

Comment: `array_map(function(&$var){  $var++; }, array(&$a,&$b,&$c,&$d));`

Comment: What is the significance of having &$var, if they are already referenced in the array part? I tested this in my server with out the &$var and it worked as expected.

Comment: @PatrickEvans You must be running 5.3.x on 5.4 and 5.5 it does not work without double references

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function that takes arguments by reference:

```
function inc_all(&$arg1, &$arg2 = 0, &$arg3 = 0, &$arg4 = 0) {
    $arg1++;
    $arg2++;
    $arg3++;
    $arg4++;
}

inc_all($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

You need to code the function for the maximum number of variables you need to increment at once, because it's not possible to pass by reference to a function that uses `func_get_args` to process arbitrary length argument lists.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. The only problem is that it is required to have 4 arguments. Would it be possible using `func_get_args` to have an unknown number of arguments all passed by reference?

Comment: I posted an answer using a modified version of `func_get_args`, found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#110030)

Comment: @Indy modifying `$trace[1]['args']` (actually it should be 0, not 1) only uses them by reference within the function. Even if you do `$trace[0]['args']++`, it will change it within the function it doesn't change the original variable.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, as it works fine for me with PHP v5.4.6 http://i.imgur.com/RyiCrqV.png

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. You will just have to waste the additional statements to increment them one by one.

Something that is applicable in other situations is that you can set multiple values at once. For example,
 `$a = $b = $c = 10;` will set both $a, $b and $c to 10.

Answer (score 1):

Since php 5.6 it is possible to use [variadics](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and handle variable number of arguments in one function:

```php
function increment(&...$arguments)
{
    foreach($arguments as &$arg){
        ++$arg;
    }
}
increment($a);
increment($b, $c);
increment($x, $y, $z);
```

Original answer:

One other example, without references:

```php
extract(array_map(function($v){return ++$v;}, compact(array('a','b','c','d'))));
```

Answer (score -1):

Using help from [this code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#110030), I managed to make a slightly more dynamic version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001386/increment-operator-on-multiple-values/18001511#18001511)

It's quite a hackjob, but this example would do the trick for up to 9 arguments.

```
// Workaround from
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#110030
function func_get_args_byref() {
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    return $trace[1]['args'];
}

// ``&x=0'', required to pass arg as reference
// You can increase the amount of maximum arguments by adding ``&$x=0''
function inc( &$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0,&$x=0 ) {
    $arguments = func_get_args_byref();
    foreach ($arguments as &$arg) ++$arg;
}

$a = 0; $b = 3; $c = 45; $d = 10;

inc($a, $b, $c, $d); // a = 1, b = 4, c = 46, d = 11
inc($b, $d);         // a = 1, b = 5, c = 46, d = 12
inc($c, $d);         // a = 1, b = 5, c = 47, d = 13
inc($a, $a, $c);     // a = 3, b = 5, c = 48, d = 13
```

Comment: Why do you bother with all the parameter variables, since you don't use them?

Comment: The [workaround](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php#110030) doesn't work without them.

Comment: Are you able to increment more variables than parameters in the argument list? If not, I guess the only benefit over my version is you don't have to put N increments in the body of the function.

Comment: By adding \`\``&$x=0`'' to the argument list, you can effectively increase the maximum amount of arguments, without changing the body of the function.